# PowerMockito.verifyStatic() Problems

Tags: java, junit, powermockito

I need to use PowerMockito to test if a specific static method is called. I am using the following PowerMockito and JUnit libraries ...

- powermock-mockito-1.6.2-full.jar
- junit-4.12.jar

I am having issues getting the PowerMockito.verifyStatic() method to work properly. In the following code example, I have tried using the @PrepareForTest, and mockStatic(), and I have tried excluding them. In the code example I include them.

Test Class:

```
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Test1.class)
public class PowerMockTest {
    @Test
    public void staticVerifyTest() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Test1.class);

        // Test
        PowerMockito.verifyStatic();
        //Test1.staticMethod();
    }
}
```

Class Under Test:

```
public class Test1 {
    public static void staticMethod() {
        System.out.println("Static Method!");
    }
}
```

The test passes when it is run, but it should fail because Test1.staticMethod() is never called. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should not use PowerMockito to test your static method because this one is not embedded in another class. A mock is used to bypass some real calls. If you want to test only the Test1 class, make a direct call to staticMethod() and add an assertion for the behaviour you want to test (a test without assertion is not a test).

Comment: Yes, I understand that this is not a good test. I am just curious as to how the verifyStatic() method works. Is it supposed to be used for a case like my above example? Thanks.

Comment: If a class A contains some static methods from class B, you can use PowerMockito to mock these static calls and test class A behaviour. You have a full example here : [http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/mockito/mockito-mock-static-method-example/](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/mockito/mockito-mock-static-method-example/). PowerMockito should be used sparingly :)

Answer (score 27):

Alright, I figured it out thanks to Stefan Birkner's [reference](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/mockito/mockito-mock-static-method-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bexample/)

Here is the correction to my sample code:

```
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Test1.class)
public class PowerMockTest {
    @Test
    public void staticVerifyTest() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Test1.class);
        // Test
        Test1.staticMethod();
        PowerMockito.verifyStatic();
        Test1.staticMethod();
    }
}
```

After the static method is invoked, you need to verify that it was called by calling it again after your verifyStatic() call.

i.e.

```
        Test1.staticMethod();
        PowerMockito.verifyStatic();
        Test1.staticMethod();
```

You can also check if it was called multiple times like this...

```
Test1.staticMethod();
Test1.staticMethod();
Test1.staticMethod();
PowerMockito.verifyStatic(Mockito.times(3));
Test1.staticMethod();
```

Comment: man oh man, i wish the documentation for this was clearer here: https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage#a-full-example-for-mocking-stubbing--verifying-static-method i wasted way too much time trying to understand why this wasn't working!

Comment: No problem! I'm glad it helped. Yes, the API is definitely not straightforward. I've learned to avoid using it and to stick with Mockito and re designing code to make it easier to test.

Comment: The reference link you posted doesn't work any longer. I am curious as to why the test passes even when the method isn't invoked?

Comment: I just tested it using the latest powermock version ([1.7.1](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Downloads)) and have verified that it will fail if you comment the first static method call, Test1.staticMethod(). Note, that PowerMockito.verifyStatic() is now deprecated in the newest version, so use PowerMockito.verifyStatic(Class<T> mockedClass) https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#how-to-verify-behavior.

Comment: @JohnAQualls Just to clarify, you're saying the test failed when you had this - `PowerMockito.mockStatic(Test1.class);  
          PowerMockito.verifyStatic();`

Comment: **The following passes**: PowerMockito.mockStatic(Test1.class); Test1.staticMethod(); PowerMockito.verifyStatic(); Test1.staticMethod();  **The following fails**:  PowerMockito.mockStatic(Test1.class); PowerMockito.verifyStatic(); Test1.staticMethod();

Comment: I'm still not clear why the sample I posted or the very first sample in the question you posted passes? Does `PowerMockito.verifyStatic()` simply indicate the existence of mockable static methods and that is the reason why it passes?

Comment: I cannot get this running with static methods taking parameters.

Comment: Why would you call a method in the test method and verify it has been called? What a bad answer. You need to call a method that calls something else and verify if that something else was called.

Answer (score 10):

It's not an answer in itself but A) a confirmation that Oliver's comment about the method change is still valid at PowerMock 2.0.2 and B) a note with additional information on how it works.

**PowerMockito.verifyStatic()** calls **Mockito.verify()** which has a few examples at its Javadoc:

```
verify(mock, times(5)).someMethod("was called five times");
verify(mock, atLeast(2)).someMethod("was called at least two times");
```

As this sintax is not available anymore we need 2 lines of code to declare the validation rule. Using John's example this means that the first 3 lines would be "actual" business calls and the one after **verifyStatic** is just telling it which call counter must match the 2nd parameter:

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(Test1.class);

// Test
Test1.staticMethod();
Test1.staticMethod();
Test1.staticMethod();

// Validation
PowerMockito.verifyStatic(Test1.class, Mockito.times(3));
Test1.staticMethod();
```

Comment: Thank you, this explained a pretty complicated syntax which PowerMockito uses for this.

Answer (score 8):

For me, I encountered this issue when upgrading to powermock `2.0.0-beta.5` from `1.7.0` and so these solutions posted above **DID NOT** help solve my problem. Instead, I had to add the mocked class inside of the verify static call as posted within the documentation for powermock (https://static.javadoc.io/org.powermock/powermock-api-mockito/1.7.1/deprecated-list.html)

So I went from:

```
PowerMockito.verifyStatic(Mockito.times(1));
```

to:

```
PowerMockito.verifyStatic(Test1.class, Mockito.times(1));
```

This solved my problem when using the libraries below:

```
testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '2.18.0'
testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-api-mockito2', version: '2.0.0-beta.5'
testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-module-junit4', version: '2.0.0-beta.5'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `powermock-api-mockito2` and `powermock-module-junit4` version 2.0.7 and either Mockito 2.28.2 or 3.3.3, with a test defined like the below, I kept getting an error about "TooManyActualInvocations: Wanted 1 time but was 2 times."

```
public class StaticClass {
  // Note: void method with arguments
  public static void doSomething(final String arg) {
    doSomethingElseWithArg(arg);
  }
}

public class ClassUnderTest {
  public void doWork(String arg) {
    StaticClass.doSomething(arg);
  } 
}

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(StaticClass.class)
public class MyTest {
  ClassUnderTest tester = new ClassUnderTest();

  @Test 
  public void myStaticTest() throws Exception {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(StaticClass.class);
    StaticClass.doSomething("hello");  // won't work

    tester.doWork("hello");

    PowerMockito.verifyStatic(StaticClass.class);
    StaticClass.doSomething("hello"); // TooManyActualInvocations 
  }
}
```

After doublechecking that the original code was not calling the method twice, much doc reading and many bunny trails, I finally got it to work. The test method needed to look like this instead:

```
@Test 
public void myStaticTest() throws Exception {
  PowerMockito.mockStatic(StaticClass.class);
  PowerMockito.doNothing().when(StaticClass.class, "doSomething", "hello"); 

  tester.doWork("hello");

  PowerMockito.verifyStatic(StaticClass.class);
  // specify the method and the args expected in the call
  StaticClass.doSomething("hello");
}
```

It took me so long to figure this out I'm documenting for the next person.

Comment: Now worked unfortunately, it gives "*verifyStatic Argument passed to verify() is of type Class and is not a mock!*" error. Any idea?

Comment: Works just fine if entered like the above.