# Test static void method using power-mockito

Tags: java, maven, junit, mockito, powermockito

I am trying to update our application on Java-11 from java-8, But there are many issues while running the test case after update with java-11. Most of the issues are with static class

I have tried referred the following doc as well but no luck

[power Mockito reference doc](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito)

[maven setup with power Mockito](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito-2-Maven)

Tools:

```
Java 11 : 

<dependency>
      <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
      <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.9</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
      <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.9</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

junit:junit:jar:4.13:test
```

```
import java.io.File;

public class IOUtils {
    public static void deleteLocalFile(final String ... fileLocs) {
            for (final String fileLoc : fileLocs) {
                System.out.println("Deleting file from path: %s", fileLoc);

                    final File file = new File(fileLoc);
                    if (file.exists() && !file.isDirectory()) {
                        if (file.delete()) {
                            System.out.println("Successfully deleted the local  file ");
                        }
                        else {
                            System.out.println("Could not delete the local  file");
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Local file doesn't exist.");
                    }

            }
        }
}
```

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyString;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.verifyStatic;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(IOUtils.class)
public class IOUtilsTest {

    @Test
    public void testDeleteLocalFile() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(IOUtils.class);
        String fileLocation = "/tmp/notExistingFile.txt";
        PowerMockito.doNothing().when(IOUtils.class, "deleteLocalFile", anyString());
        IOUtils.deleteLocalFile(fileLocation);
        verifyStatic(times(1));
    }
}
```

Exception

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.7.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java 
org.objenesis.ObjenesisException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

    at org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryHelper.newConstructorForSerialization(SunReflectionFactoryHelper.java:54)
    at org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.<init>(SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.java:41)
    at org.objenesis.strategy.StdInstantiatorStrategy.newInstantiatorOf(StdInstantiatorStrategy.java:68)
    at org.objenesis.ObjenesisBase.getInstantiatorOf(ObjenesisBase.java:94)
    at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.newInstance(WhiteboxImpl.java:259)
    at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.newInstance(Whitebox.java:139)
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.getPowerMockTestListenersLoadedByASpecificClassLoader(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:95)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:174)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:48)
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.createTestDelegators(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:108)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.<init>(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:71)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.<init>(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:32)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.<init>(PowerMockRunner.java:34)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:36)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:50)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryHelper.newConstructorForSerialization(SunReflectionFactoryHelper.java:44)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class jdk.internal.reflect.ConstructorAccessorImpl loaded by org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader @5c909414 cannot access jdk/internal/reflect superclass jdk.internal.reflect.MagicAccessorImpl
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadUnmockedClass(MockClassLoader.java:250)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:194)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass1(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:77)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:67)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadUnmockedClass(MockClassLoader.java:250)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:194)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass1(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:77)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:67)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.defineClass0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(Unsafe.java:1194)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ClassDefiner.defineClass(ClassDefiner.java:63)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:400)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:394)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generate(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:393)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generateSerializationConstructor(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:112)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.generateConstructor(ReflectionFactory.java:514)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newConstructorForSerialization(ReflectionFactory.java:427)
    at jdk.unsupported/sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newConstructorForSerialization(ReflectionFactory.java:98)
    ... 32 more


Process finished with exit code 255
```

Comment: I found it tricky to get static void validation working too. Your test code looks like [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62785575/944849) except for the post test validation at the bottom. Maybe adjusting will help.

Comment: I did try that as well before posting the issue here. I am not able to understand what is the issue here, it is because of JDK-11 or because of power-mockito version
Thank you @user944849 for your response.